# Transformando linhas em colunas

Tags: mysql

Gostaria de transformar alguns valores da tabela em colunas.
A estrutura da tabela seria basicamente essa:

```
| id | idUnidade | mesCompetencia | valor |
|----|-----------|----------------|-------|
| 1  | 237       | 2017-05-01     | 35    |
| 2  | 237       | 2017-06-01     | 45    |
|
```

Meu select faz a busca dos dados entre duas datas, simplificando seriam dois meses, e gostaria que os valores fossem atribuidos a coluna "valorCompetencia" e "valorAnterior" em uma única linha agrupada pelo código da unidade.

**SQL atual**

```
SELECT 
    idUnidade,
    MONTH(MIN(mesCompetencia)) as mesAnterior,
    MONTH(MAX(mesCompetencia)) as mesAtual,

    #---------TENTATIVAS SEM SUCESSO---------
    #[Err] 1111 - Invalid use of group function
    SUM(CASE MONTH(mesCompetencia) WHEN MONTH(MIN(mesCompetencia)) THEN valor END) as valorAnterior
    #[Err] 1111 - Invalid use of group function
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(mesCompetencia) = MONTH(MIN(mesCompetencia)) THEN valor END) as valorAnterior
    #[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'mesAnterior' in 'field list'
    SUM(CASE MONTH(mesCompetencia) WHEN mesAnterior THEN valor END) as valorAnterior
    #[Err] 1111 - Invalid use of group function
    SUM( if (MIN(mesCompetencia) = mesCompetencia, valor, 0)) as valorAnterior
    #[Err] 1111 - Invalid use of group function
    SUM(CASE WHEN MIN(mesCompetencia) = mesCompetencia THEN valor ELSE 0 END) as valorAnterior
    #[Err] 1111 - Invalid use of group function    
    SUM(CASE MIN(mesCompetencia) WHEN mesCompetencia THEN valor ELSE 0 END) as valorAnterior

FROM Tabela 
WHERE ....... mesCompetencia BETWEEN 'X' AND 'Y' .....
GROUP BY idUnidade
```

Com este SQL (ignorando as tentativas sem sucesso) tenho o seguinte resultado:

```
| idUnidade | mesAtual | mesAnterior |
|-----------|----------------|-------------|
| 237       | 06             | 05
|
```

Porém o resultado que eu gostaria é:

```
| idUnidade | mesAtual | mesAnterior | valorCompetencia | valorAnterior |
|-----------|----------|-------------|------------------|---------------|
| 237       | 06       | 05          | 45               |  35       
|
|
```

As tentativas que fiz estão listadas no SQL que está lá em cima, alguém poderia me ajudar a agrupar esses valores?

**OBS:** Se houver uma solução sem subselects seria interessante, pois há muitas outras claúsulas no where que foram ocultadas.

Comment: O jeito mais rápido que pensei aqui seria fazendo um subselect.. por exemplo select idUnidade, (select valor from Tabela where mes=MAX(mesCompetencia)) as valorCompetencia

Comment: @Lucas Seria uma possibilidade, mas é dessa situação que queria fugir por causa das clausulas do where que teriam que ser inclusas neste sub-select (fiz um obs no final da pergunta); Até o momento contornei a situação através da programação... Agradeço sua atenção :)